# Strange behavior of generator from function

Tags: python, python-3.x, generator

While playing with generators, I found interesting thing. When I defined a function with `yield` keyword, received a generator from it, I also deleted the variable with sequence, which was fed to function. And *POOF!* - generator become empty. Here's my steps:

```
>>> def foo(list_):
...     for i in list_:
...             yield i*2
... 
>>> val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> gen = foo(val)
>>> print(tuple(gen))
(2, 4, 6, 8)
>>> del val
>>> print(tuple(gen))
()
>>>
```

Shouldn't it be immutable? Or, if it actually works as object which feeds all values of it's variable to it's function, giving the output, why it didn't throws an exception due to absence of linked sequence? Actually, that example can be explained as if I iterate over a empty sequence, which results that block `for _ in []:` wouldn't ever start. But, I cant explain why **this** does not throw an exception:

```
>>> def foo(list_):
...     for i in list_:
...             yield i*2
... 
>>> val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> gen = foo(val)
>>> print(tuple(gen))
(2, 4, 6, 8)
>>> del foo
>>> print(tuple(gen))
()
>>>
```

Are generators act here similar to `dict.get()` function? I don't understand this.

Comment: The fact that you did `del val` has nothing to do with the generator behavior you observed. If you didn't `del val`, you would have seen the same results.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This has nothing to do with objects being deleted. Instead, you have exhausted the generator; generators can only be iterated over once. Create a new generator from the generator function if you need to iterate a second time. You see the same behaviour without deleting references:

```
>>> def foo(list_):
...     for i in list_:
...         yield i*2
...
>>> val = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> gen = foo(val)
>>> list(gen)
[2, 4, 6, 8]
>>> list(gen)  # gen is now exhausted, so no more elements are produced
[]
>>> gen = foo(val)  # new generator
>>> list(gen)
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Note that `del foo` or `del val` only deletes the *reference* to an object. It wouldn't delete the function or list object altogether if there are other references to it, like from an existing generator created from the function. So `gen = foo(val); del foo, val` won't break the `gen` object, it can still produce values without either the `foo` or `val` references existing, because `gen` itself still references what it needs to complete:

```
>>> gen = foo(val)
>>> del foo, val
>>> list(gen)  # gen still references the list and code objects
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

Comment: Ok, but what happens when I use `itertools.tee()` on my generator, after deleting both function and sequence?

Comment: @MaxLunar: `tee()` uses references too. Everything in Python does. `del` only removes the name, which then decrements the reference count. Only when the count goes to 0 is an object actually deleted.

Comment: @MaxLunar: In other words, you can then use the teed-off generator objects to still get at the generated items.